# "There had emerged" <--- What does "there" mean here?

Tags: meaning, past-perfect, there-is

> ***There had emerged*** on the steppes of Inner Eurasia the distinctive types of pastoralism that were ***to dominate*** the region’s history for several millennia.

I have questions about the excerpt above:

1. What is the meaning of "there" in "there had emerged", which tense is that, can I say it in a different way and how?
2. Why the writer used "were to dominate" not "were dominating"?

Comment: On #2, have a look at this archived blog on [*talking about future situations*](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10555/142322). In particular, look at the part talking about "BE + to" (do a text search on the linked page to go straight to it).